# Angular + (Jasmine/Karma) - Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm really trying to solve this error and nothing on the internet helps me for the moment...

**`lr-categories.component.spec.ts`:**

```
export function main() {
  describe('LrCategoriesComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LrCategoriesComponent>;
    let component: LrCategoriesComponent;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let glService: GeneralLedgeService;
    let lrService: LrService;
    let spy: jasmine.Spy;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
          LrComponent,
          LrMappingsComponent,
          LrCategoriesComponent,
        ],
        imports: [
          CommonModule,
          SharedModule,
          LrRoutingModule,
          AgGridModule.withComponents(
            [
              ButtonComponent,
              ColumnHeaderComponent,
              TypeaheadEditorComponent,
              ButtonGroupComponent
            ]
          )
        ],
        providers: [
          LrService,
          { provide: GeneralLedgeService, useClass: MockGeneralLedgeService },
          CompleterService,
        ]
      }).compileComponents().then(() => {
        // initialization
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LrCategoriesComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement;

        // Service getters
        glService = de.injector.get(GeneralLedgeService);
        lrService = de.injector.get(LrService);
      });
    }));

    // beforeEach(() => {
    //   // initialization
    //   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LrCategoriesComponent);
    //   component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //   de = fixture.debugElement;
    //
    //   // Service getters
    //   glService = de.injector.get(GeneralLedgeService);
    //   lrService = de.injector.get(LrService);
    // });

    it('should create LrCategoriesComponent', (() => {
      expect(component).toBeDefined();
    }));
  });
}
```

**ERROR:**
[image]

> ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Illegal state: Could not load
>   the summary for directive LrCategoriesComponent.'

Any suggestions are accepted! I'm desperate at this point!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, I'll walk you through it ***(SOLUTION is point 3)***:

**1. I moved the initialization** stuff from `.compileComponents().then(() => {...});` to `beforeEach(() => {...});`.
 *(You can see it was commented)*

```
export function main() {
  describe('LrCategoriesComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LrCategoriesComponent>;
    let component: LrCategoriesComponent;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let glService: GeneralLedgeService;
    let lrService: LrService;
    let spy: jasmine.Spy;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        // Module's stuff here
      }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
      // initialization
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LrCategoriesComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      de = fixture.debugElement;

      // Service getters
      glService = de.injector.get(GeneralLedgeService);
      lrService = de.injector.get(LrService);
    });

    it('should create LrCategoriesComponent', (() => {
      expect(component).toBeDefined();
    }));
  });
}
```

This gave me the following error:

> Error: This test module uses the component ToolBarComponent which is
>   using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled.

This error is because one of the Components declared in `SharedModule` had issues while compiling (actually, this happened with any component in the `declarations[]` of `SharedModule`).

So, I started looking for ways to solve the setup of a spec file when importing `SharedModule` (or other heavy modules).

**2. I found a new approach [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12409#issuecomment-322832870):**

```
const oldResetTestingModule = TestBed.resetTestingModule;
    beforeAll(done => (async () => {
      TestBed.resetTestingModule();
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       // Module's stuff here
      });
      await TestBed.compileComponents();

      // prevent Angular from resetting testing module
      TestBed.resetTestingModule = () => TestBed;
    })().then(done).catch(done.fail));

    afterAll(() => {
      // reinstate resetTestingModule method
      TestBed.resetTestingModule = oldResetTestingModule;
      TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    });
```

Even though it **finally worked everything** and at an amazing speed *(5 seconds vs 20 seconds before)*, **this approach has a main downside**: Dependencies are created once per `describe()`, not per test. Meaning that **you inherit the *state* from the previous test case**. We don't want that!

**3.** I went back to square one, **tried to understand and apply a smarter async logic...:**

**- SOLUTION -**

```
beforeEach(done => (async () => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        // Module's stuff here, including SharedModule
      });
      await TestBed.compileComponents();
    })().then(done).catch(done.fail));

    beforeEach(() => {
      // initialization
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LrCategoriesComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      de = fixture.debugElement;

      // Service getters
      glService = de.injector.get(GeneralLedgeService);
      lrService = de.injector.get(LrService);
    });
```

by playing with **`async / await`** I make sure that the *Module* is correctly configured before attempting to compile the *Component*.

With this, **I manage to compile the component and have a clean and fresh instance to test on for each test case scenario!**

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and all I had to do was to return the promise from beforeEach as below

```
beforeEach(() => {  

  return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        .... setup code
     }).compileComponents().then(() => {
        ...initialization....
    });
  });

});
```